# What meaning does "as" bring to the definition?

Tags: prepositions

I googled what radiance means and the result is

> light or heat **as** emitted or reflected by something.

Could you explain the role of "as" here? I can see no reason to put it in, as sentence without the preposition also makes sense and has the same meaning.

Comment: Did you look up 'as' in the same dictionary you found 'radiance' in? There are lots of different uses, admittedly, but one does fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **as**
> pronoun
> : that, who, which
> —used after same or such and chiefly dialect after a substantive not modified by same or such

So, your example means light or heat **such as that** emitted or reflected by something.